# Javascript: Pass the method inside addEventListener

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
class Validate {

    validateFormSubmit(element, constraints) {
      document.querySelector(element)
        .addEventListener("submit", function(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
          this.handleFormSubmit(this);
      });
    }

    handleFormSubmit(form, constraints) {
      console.log('success');
    }

}
```

> Error: Undefined handleFormSubmit

How do I get the handleFormSubmit correctly? when I `console.log(this)` inside is the selected element. Please advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the meaning of `this` is changed in the callback. Use an arrow function instead:

```
document.querySelector(element)
  .addEventListener("submit", ev => {
      ev.preventDefault();
      this.handleFormSubmit(this);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

`addEventListener` has own scope that is why It is conflicting with parent scope so use `context` variable in order to access class scope inside `addEventListener`.

```
class Validate {

    validateFormSubmit(element, constraints) {
      const context = this;
      document.querySelector(element)
        .addEventListener("submit", function(ev) {
          ev.preventDefault();
          context.handleFormSubmit(this);
      });
    }

    handleFormSubmit(form, constraints) {
      console.log('success');
    }

}
```

and you can do this without using `context` by using `bind` but in this event scope will override to class scope.

```
document.querySelector(element)
    .addEventListener("submit", (function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        this.handleFormSubmit(this); // this changed to class scope
    }).bind(this));
```

Comment: Its working using your way or arrow function above! thanks!